# How do I insert a character at the beginning of each line of a paragraph that contains a string

Tags: sed

Sort of different request here: I have a text file in which I need to place a `@` character at the beginning of each paragraph (paragraphs=separated by blank lines) that contains a certain search string. For example

```
hello

this
is
a
test

hi
```

Should yield:

```
hello

@this
@is
@a
@test

hi
```

I have the following for selective printing of a paragraph, but it won't insert the `#` character at the beginning of each line:

```
sed -e '/./{H;$!d;}' -e 'x;/SEARCH_STRING/!d;'
```

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have acces to GNU sed?

Comment: i don't believe so, no.  This is the sed v4.1.4 SUSE Linux, i'm open to other ways to do it also

Comment: Why is your example gone?

Comment: it edited it out because it didn't come out the way i needed it to, some issue with the line feeds

Comment: Try to prefix lines of your example with four whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it largely a matter of replacing the final `!d` ('don't delete') with `s/\n/\n@/g;` ('substitute newlines by newlines plus an additional character')?

```
$ cat file
hello

this
is
a
test

hi
```

```
$ sed -e '1{x;$!d}' -e '/./{H;$!d;}' -e 'x;/test/ s/\n/\n@/g;' file
hello

@this
@is
@a
@test

hi
```

The extra expression `1{x;$!d}` just prevents an additional blank line that would otherwise result from appending the first line to the (empty) hold space.

Comment: one last thing- is it possible to designate either a blank space OR a colon (:) to separate paragraphs?